# How To Set Up Bazaar Server On Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, bazaar

How do you set up a Bazaar server on Ubuntu server? I have home server running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS I want to use as a Bazaar central server. How do I do that? (create repository (if not the same), open ports for listening, create users...).

**Edited**

I found a blog that has stuff needed for a server to be started. But... How do you limit rights for users? Give some users rights to upload, others - download and etc.

Here is the blog: http://zeth.net/post/366/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a blog in which some guy talks about setting up a Bazaar server as they didn't want to publish their code (just like me): http://zeth.net/post/366/

Firstly, they made a new user for Bazaar (to keep everything nice and clean):

```
$ sudo useradd -m bzruser
```

After the user was set up, they simply created a regular repository there:

```
$ sudo su bzruser
$ mkdir -p /home/bzruser/repository/group/project/trunk
$ cd /home/bzruser/repository/group/project/trunk
$ bzr init
```

When the repo is created, you simply start the server by using

```
$ bzr server --directory=/home/bzruser/repository
```

Which starts listening to port 4155 (though it can be changed using *--port* option).

Of course, directory hierarchy is up to you, the admin, as well as stuff like making the server start on boot, but it's a different story. Bazaar server is up and running ;)

Comment: After doing everything just as you described have the following problem:

Comment: damian@damian-desktop:~/Pulpit$ bzr checkout bzr+ssh://testpxe.servebeer.com/home/tomasz/bzr/test1 testowy-projekt1
bzr: ERROR: Permission denied: "/home/tomasz/bzr/test1/.bzr/branch-format": : [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/tomasz/bzr/test1/.bzr/branch-format'
damian@damian-desktop:~/Pulpit$

Answer (score 2):

I host my Bazaar repositories via WebDAV. Note that this is *not* the preferred method because repacking involves lots of traffic (SSH or smart server does not have this problem). That is why I run "bzr pack" via cron at night time for all repos. WebDAV is a good solution if you don't want to open up another port, or want to use the authentication methods of Apache like I do. It is the easiest solution in my opinion.

Create the file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/bzr-repos` (name does not matter, but any file in conf.d is included automatically):

```
# This assumes you have your repos in /var/bzr-repos which should be owned
# (or at least read-and-writable) by the user www-data
Alias /bzr /var/bzr-repos
<Directory /var/bzr-repos>
    DAV On
    Options Indexes

    # The bzr.webdav plugin for http(s)+webdav transport
    # only works with this option:
    DirectorySlash Off
</Directory>
<Location /bzr>
    # Put SSLRequireSSL here if you want
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Then you can add single repositories like so:

```
# Repo stored in /var/bzr-repos/my-repo-name
<Location /bzr/my-repo-name>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    # If you want authentication (I guess so, or do you want everyone to
    # be able to push and pull?)
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/my-passwords.passwd
    Require user my-username
</Location>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache then. You might have to enable the DAV module (`a2enmod dav dav_fs`).

In order to use the repository, use the URL "http+webdav://example.com/bzr/my-repo-name/" (or `https+webdav://` for HTTPS).

Answer (score 1):

### [Bazaar in five minutes](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.0/en/mini-tutorial/index.html)

If you follow this nice and short tutorial you will be able to create a **local** Bazaar branch, commit your code, and push it to any location including [Launchpad](https://help.launchpad.net/CreatingYourLaunchpadAccount) (not really in five minutes but certainly in minutes rather than hours):

A complete tutorial for advanced Bazaar usage can be found here:

[Bazaar User Guide](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.0/en/user-guide/index.html)

Comment: I don't want to publish my code. I want to make my own central server for Bazaar. A private Bazaar server or whatever it's called.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find it there but I found a blog that does show what commands are used for the server to be started.

Comment: I edited it into my first post. I will make it as an Answer.